# Double integral with even function cancellation of variable by symetry

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck with understanding how to go from this integral: $$\int \int _Q \frac{x^2+y^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}dA$$
where $Q$ is the first quadrant in $x-y$ plane, to this:

$$2\int \int _Q\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}dA$$

I was reading a book and the author went from one to the other and only added (by symetry) as justification. However, I don't really understand which symetry he is referring to.

Comment: $$\iint_{Q}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\,dA = \iint_{Q}\frac{y^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\,dA$$ since the first quadrant is invariant with respect to the substitution $(x,y)\mapsto(y,x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by "Invariant w.r.t the substitution"?

Comment: I mean that the first quadrant is symmetric with respect to the bisector of the first and third quadrant, hence $$\iint_Q f(x,y)\,dA = \iint_Q f(y,x)\,dA$$

Comment: I think I am a bit confused about the hence part. Why is the function being symetric on the first and third quadrant imply $\iint_Q f(x,y)\,dA = \iint_Q f(y,x)\,dA$. Is there some theory here that I am missing?

Comment: It is not the function being symmetric, it is the integration domain that is symmetric!